# Approximating integral with a pole

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, asymptotics, singularity, singular-integrals

Let $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the integral $$\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \frac{|\sin(x)|^{-\lambda i}}{x}dx.$$ I'd like to approximate it as $\lambda\to\infty$. Without the singularity in $x=0$, that would be done using the theory of stationary phase. However, I'm not sure how to address the contribution of the pole at $x=0$ to this integral.

How can I get the asymptotic for this integral?

Comment: i would deform the contour of integration around the pole and see what happens

Comment: @tired you mean something like semicircle around $x$?

Comment: exactly. because the pole is on the contour, you don't really have much other choices other then deformation

Comment: @tired if I do so, for a semicircle of radius 1 around $x=0$, using Cauchy's integral formula I get $\int_{[0,\pi]}\frac{\sin^{-\lambda i}e^{it}}{e^{it}}dt=2\pi i \sin(1)^{-\lambda i}$. Adding the vertical paths, the decay is $c\cdot |\lambda|^{-\frac 1 2}+\sin(1)^{\lambda i} = O(0.8^{\lambda i})$. Is that the best decay we can expect?

Comment: ( take my word with some care i didnt calculate anything by myself) i think you are totally right, let me know your final results i am really interested.